# Cannot include image from sections

Tags: image, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I wrote an asciidoctor document with includes and the following structure :

```
/mydoc.adocs
/chap1/
/chap1/chap1.adoc
/chap1/sections/
/chap1/sections/section1.adoc
/chap1/images/
/chap1/images/myimg.png
/img/
/img/...some other images here
```

I generate my PDF with the following command :

```
asciidoctor-pdf -b pdf mydoc.adoc
```

The mydoc.adoc looks like this :

```
:doctype: book
:encoding: utf-8
:imagesdir: img

= My life...
Thierry <thierry@mywebsite.com>

include::chap1/chap1.adoc[]
```

The chap1.adoc looks like this :

```
[[_Chap1]]
== Foo
include::sections/section1.adoc[]
```

And finally the section1.adoc looks like this :

```
=== Bla bla
image::../images/myimg.png[label]
```

If I generate the PDF for section1.adoc (asciidoctor-pdf -b pdf section1.adoc), it includes the image. But If I generate the PDF for mydoc.adoc (asciidoctor-pdf -b pdf mydoc.adoc) from the root, it does not include the image.

And I get the following error :

```
asciidoctor: WARNING: image to embed not found or not readable: C:/myproject/images/myimg.png
```

I looks like as if the generation does not take care of the paths...

Can someone help me ?

Th.

Comment: Can you specify the version you are using? And how you generate your document (command line, maven, gradle, ...)? 
Images and Includes sections are tricky, but as far as I know the bugs were resolved in the latest versions. Check the value of `{imagesdir}` variable in your documents.

Comment: On the Asciidoctor Mailing List: http://discuss.asciidoctor.org/Cannot-include-image-from-sub-sections-td4761.html

Answer (score 0):

your request is unfortunately a bit older, but I run into same probblem and solved it as follows. Im running Ubuntu 20.04, but installed podman and using a CentOS7 container to install asciidoctor-pdf in it. So you have to choose any operating system which is capable of running containers.

## Install dockerized asciidoctor-pdf (with .png-support)

The standard installation of asciidoctor-pdf and the official docker hub image 
does not support converting .adoc to .pdf using .png files. You will get an error. In the example I try to convert service-documentation.adoc to service-documentation.pdf:

```
$ podman run --rm -v $(pwd):/documents/ asciidoctor/docker-asciidoctor asciidoctor-pdf service-documentation.adoc 
Trying to pull docker.io/asciidoctor/docker-asciidoctor...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob 85a3f8045a5f done  
Copying blob 6cf8cbf780aa done  
Copying blob c9b1b535fdd9 done  
Copying blob 07903a9ac4b8 done  
Copying blob 102cbf696e41 done  
Copying config 0c383e26e3 done  
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures

asciidoctor: WARNING: could not embed image: image.png; PNG uses unsupported interlace method; install prawn-gmagick gem to add support
asciidoctor:
```

## Prepare container

I am using podman to create the needed container

## Run CentOS7 Container

I am using a CentOS7 container from docker.io to install asciidoctor-pdf in it:

```
podman run -ti --name asciidoctor-pdf -v $(pwd):/data centos:centos7 /bin/bash
```

## Install epel repo and update system

Etra packages for enterprise linux are needed, so install yum repu using 
following comand:

```
$ yum install epel-release -y 
$ yum update -y
```

## Install ruby

Asciidoctor uses ruby, install ruby:

```
$ yum install which git wget -y
$ curl -L get.rvm.io |bash -s stable
$ gpg2 --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
$ curl -L get.rvm.io |bash -s stable
$ source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
$ rvm reload
$ rvm requirements run
$ rvm install 2.6
$ ruby -v

ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-linux]
```

## Install asciidoctor-pdf

Asciidoctor without full .png support can now be installed using the following 
command:

```
$ gem install asciidoctor-pdf --pre
$ asciidoctor-pdf -v

Asciidoctor PDF 1.5.3 using Asciidoctor 2.0.10 [https://asciidoctor.org]
Runtime Environment (ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-linux]) (lc:US-ASCII fs:US-ASCII in:US-ASCII ex:US-ASCII)
```

## Install Graphics Magick (for prawn-gmagick)

To support .png files we need gem prawn-gmagick. The requirement for this is 
graphics-magick. Install it using following command:

```
$ yum install GraphicsMagick-c++ GraphicsMagick-devel libpng libjpeg libpng-devel ghostscript libtiff libtiff-devel freetype freetype-devel jasper jasper-devel -y
$ mkdir ~/temp
$ cd ~/temp
$ wget ftp://ftp.graphicsmagick.org/pub/GraphicsMagick/GraphicsMagick-LATEST.tar.gz
$ tar xvzf GraphicsMagick-LATEST.tar.gz 
$ cd GraphicsMagick-1.3.35/
$ ./configure
$ make install
$ gm version

GraphicsMagick 1.3.35 2020-02-23 Q8 http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/
Copyright (C) 2002-2020 GraphicsMagick Group.
Additional copyrights and licenses apply to this software.
See http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/www/Copyright.html for details.

Feature Support:
  Native Thread Safe         yes
  Large Files (> 32 bit)     yes
  Large Memory (> 32 bit)    yes
  BZIP                       no
  DPS                        no
  FlashPix                   no
  FreeType                   yes
  Ghostscript (Library)      no
  JBIG                       no
  JPEG-2000                  yes
  JPEG                       yes
  Little CMS                 no
  Loadable Modules           no
  Solaris mtmalloc           no
  Google perftools tcmalloc  no
  OpenMP                     yes (201107 "3.1")
  PNG                        yes
  TIFF                       yes
  TRIO                       no
  Solaris umem               no
  WebP                       no
  WMF                        no
  X11                        no
  XML                        no
  ZLIB                       yes
...
...
```

## Install prawn-gmagick

Now we can go ahead and install gem prawn-gmagick using following command:

```
$ gem install prawn-gmagick

Fetching prawn-gmagick-0.0.9.gem
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed prawn-gmagick-0.0.9
Parsing documentation for prawn-gmagick-0.0.9
Installing ri documentation for prawn-gmagick-0.0.9
Done installing documentation for prawn-gmagick after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Setup is finished, quit the container:

```
[root@4e5f3c876eb5 GraphicsMagick-1.3.35]# exit
exit
user@hostname-linux:~/git/service-docs$
```

## Run asciidoctor-pdf

Now we can use our created asciidoctor-pdf container with .png support described 
as folllows:

## Start container

```
$ podman start asciidoctor-pdf
$ podman exec -ti asciidoctor-pdf /bin/bash
```

## Convert .adoc to .pdf

Convert .adoc to .pdf:

```
asciidoctor-pdf file.adoc -o /data/file.pdf
```

Quit container:

```
[root@4e5f3c876eb5 GraphicsMagick-1.3.35]# exit
exit
user@hostname-linux:~/git/service-docs$
```

[TIP]
Converted files are located in cwd.

```
user@hostname-linux:~/git/service-docs$ ls -la 

total 748
...
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 744314 Mai  2 13:40 file.pdf
```

[TIP]
This is not really a problem of asciidoctor. Asciidoctor is able to convert documentation in asciidoc format with png files to html. When converting asciidoc documentation with png files to pdf it seems that you need additional libraries from prawn-magick. Prawn Magick needs Graphicks Magick. After Prawn Magick is installed, all dependencies are fulfilled to convert .adoc directly into .pdf.

Greets